# Strange marker in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2012, fortran

I tried searching here, in Microsoft's help pages and in Google, but couldn't find what the symbol in the picture means!

The symbol is a bold black line, positioned in the column where the break-point is marked usually.
It's on a generic subroutine (coding in Fortran), nothing special about it...

[image: Image of the black line]

Comment: Is there a tool-tip when you hover over it?

Comment: Nope, nothing.
If a break-point is placed, than the symbol is on top of it and covers it

Comment: OK, I got this one figured out:

If one does a search in the entire file (where the search results are shown in a list), this marker appears on the currently selected item from that list, whether the list is shown or not - so if one does search and does not empty the search results, this line will remain near the most recent selection from the list.

Emptying the list cleared the line as well.

Comment: @TheWhitestOfFangs You can post your comment as an answer and accept it if it solved your problem.

Comment: I second @Yossarian comment. Please copy and paste the comment as an answer. The future generations need to know this (since `Fortran` is going to be alive _forever_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got this one figured out:
If one does a search in the entire file (where the search results are shown in a list), this marker appears on the currently selected item from that list, whether the list is shown or not - so if one does search and does not empty the search results, this line will remain near the most recent selection from the list.
Emptying the list cleared the line as well.

Comment: The scariest part is that it shows up as a blue line in the source control comparison. Confused the hell out of me until I saw this answer.